# Ready for use with Spring Boot 3.x?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

In GitHub, I see that Spring Session 3.0.0 has been released: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/releases/tag/3.0.0

However, on Spring.io, I see that it is marked pre-release (still RC2): https://spring.io/projects/spring-session#learn

Has Spring Session 3.0.0 (final) been released? If so, is it good to go with Spring Boot 3.x?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it has been released, you will even get it if you let Spring Boot manage your dependencies. They just didn't update that part of the site yet (probably not automated).

Comment: Spring Session 3.2 is GA (https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/index.html). I'm not sure if this question should remain on the site, since it was only helpful in a short timeframe.